# How to efficiently store variable number of scipy sparse.csr_matrix in memory?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have around 10,000 sparse matrices each with size 50,000x5 with 0.0004 density on average.
For each loop (10000 times), I'm calculating numpy array and converting it into csr_matrix and appending that to a list. But memory consumption is as high as appending numpy arrays but not as appending csr_matrices.

How to reduce the memory consumption while having these 10K sparse matrices in memory for further computations?

Sample code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
sparse_matrices = []

for i in range(10000):
    np_array = get_np_array()
    sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(np_array)
    sparse_matrices.append(sparse_matrix)
    print np_array.nbytes, sparse_matrix.data.nbytes, repr(sparse_matrix)
```

Would outputs something similar which makes it clear that I'm appending compressed matrices. But still, the memory grows as same as appending numpy matrices.

```
1987520 520 <49688x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 65 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
1987520 512 <49688x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 64 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

---

Just realised that if I use `coo_matrix` instead of `csr_matrix`, memory consumption is reasonable. If that is `csr_matrix` memory's around ~8gb.

Comment: hmm, `But memory consumption is as high as appending numpy arrays but not as appending csr_matrices.` - i can't reproduce this behaviour

Comment: Just realised that if I use coo_matrix instead of csr_matrix, memory consumption is reasonable. If that is csr_matrix memory's around ~8gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the matrix:

```
<49688x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 65 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

in `coo` format, the key attributes are `row`, `col` and `data`, all with 65 elements.  `data` is float, the others integers (row and column indices).

In `csr` format the `row` attribute is replaced with `indptr`, which has one value per row (plus 1?).  With this shape `indptr` is 49688 elements long.  If it was `csc` format `indptr` would only be 5 elements.

`csr` usually is more compact that `coo`.  But in your case there are many blank rows; so it is much larger.  `csr` will be especially compact if it is a single row matrix; and not compact at all if it is a column vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the `indptr` explanation.